# How solidified lava helped find the history of Earth's magnetism?

Tags: geophysics, geomagnetism

I came to know that the earth's magnetic axis is shifting, and a proof to this involves analysing the solid lava found near volcanoes for centuries.

[image: lava]

How does lava analysis help in finding the shift in magnetic axis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least some types of lava [contain iron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lava#Lava_composition) as a magnetic ingredient. In such a case the hot lava has temperatures above the Curie temperature of iron. This means that the magnetic moments can align to the external magnetic field. This is the earth's magnetic field. When the lava cools down there is a transition to the ferromagnetic phase such that the magnetic moments get a fixed alignment to the external magnetic field at that time.